# STOMP Over WebSocket in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cordova, websocket, stomp

I have a server websocket, and I have a web UI use STOMP Over WebSocket to connect to server, now i'm creating an mobile aplication using angularjs + cordova. How to implement STOMP Over WebSocket in my application.
   When i do

```
var socket = new $window.SockJS(SOCKJS_URL, null, options);
var stompClient = $window.Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient.connect( {}, function() {
    console.log('ok');
}, null);
```

it return error : 
    Whoops! Lost connection to undefined

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are passing wrong parameters to the connect method, try this way:

```
var stompClient = $window.Stomp.over(new $window.SockJS(wsUrl));
stompClient.connect(null, null, function(frame) {
  console.log("[STOMP] Connect: " + frame);
}
```